# How to mock WS client and provide response in camel route

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, apache-camel

I want to mock WS client call in camel route, check request and provide response.

Here is a test

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import org.apache.camel.*;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * @author deveproject
 * @version 9/15/14
 */
public class WsClientMockTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Produce(uri = "direct:test-ws-client-mock")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Override
    public String isMockEndpoints() {
        return "cxf:bean:greeterService";
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetActionRoute() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint greeterService = getMockEndpoint("mock:cxf:bean:greeterService");

        greeterService.expectedMessagesMatches(new Predicate() {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                assertEquals("U.S.", exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                return true;
            }
        });
        template.sendBody("U.S.");


        greeterService.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
    }
}
```

The org.apache.camel.Predicate checks is request is correct. 
I cannot find a way how to provide a response.

I have working example with above test. I can publish it on demand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`returnReplyBody(Expession expression)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-mock/4.0.0-RC1/org/apache/camel/component/mock/MockEndpoint.html#returnReplyBody(org.apache.camel.Expression)) method for a mock response.

```
@Test
public void testGetActionRoute() throws Exception {
  MockEndpoint greeterService = getMockEndpoint("mock:cxf:bean:greeterService");

  GreeterServiceResponse response = new GreeterServiceResponse();
  response.setGreeting("Hello!");
  greeterService.returnReplyBody(constant(response));

  greeterService.expectedMessagesMatches(exchange -> {
    assertEquals("U.S.", exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    return true;
  });
  template.sendBody("U.S.");
    
  greeterService.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Comment: It helps me as well. Thanks Vladimir!

Comment: This helped me too. Thank you!